# Dark Theme in GAMS studio

Tags: gams-math

Is it possible to have dark theme (instead of white) in GMAS studio?

I've search through Internet but I couldn't find anything useful.

Thanks

[image: Editor Tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change this in the `Settings` dialog on the `Editor` tab. At least, if you use the latest version. For macOS this can be done for a while already. For other platforms this was introduced with version 1.0.0.

Comment: Hi @lutz Setting> Editor and then what? I use GAMS 27.3 .0 . In my Editor& Log Tab, I can't see anything that related to dark mode.I've added the picture of editor tab. Is dark mode only for version 31?

Comment: Which versions support dark mode? (In Windows)

Comment: It is called "Studio Appearance". But your version is too old. Studio 1.1 was part of GAMS 31. You can also get it independent of GAMS through gitHub (https://github.com/GAMS-dev/studio/releases). Though, if you try to use it with GAMS 27.3, you might run into some incompatibilities.